# One question about vector push_back

Tags: c++, vector

I just noticed that for vector push_back it is push back a reference to the element.

```
void push_back ( const T& x );
```

My question is does the memory layout changed after push_back?

For example, I have an array first which containing five elements and the layout is like this.

```
|          |          |          |          |          |              
|   A1     |     A2   |   A3     |    A4    |    A5    |
```

Now I have a vector v

```
v.push_back(A3)
```

Now, how does the memory look like?

How does the vector store the elements here?

How does the vector access the element?

Comment: Take a look at vector::reserve and vector::capacity regarding memory layout.  Keep in mind that since the memory allocation may change, any iterators you had before the push_back call become invalidated once you modify the contents of the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A vector stores by value not by reference**.

When you re-add the same element, a copy will be stored at the end.  If you do not want to make a copy of the values you are inserting into the `vector`, then you should use pointers instead.

Example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
string s = "";
v.push_back(s);
s = "hi";
v.push_back(s);
```

`v` now contains 2 different elements, one with an empty string, and one with a string which contains `"hi"`.  Both strings in the vector remain independent from `s`.

Note: The internal implementation details of an STL container can vary, there is no guarantee that it will be implemented a certain way; however, the semantics of how an STL container works, will remain the same no matter what the internal implementation is.

Comment: The semantics of std::vector<T> however do include the memory format, it is required to be in contiguous memory as of the 2003 "TC1".  All implementations have always done it this way anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**Now, how does the memory look like?** and **How does the vector store the elements here?**

There are two possible outcomes:

1. The vector's memory block is not large enough to contain the items, therefore the underlying memory is reallocated. Objects are copied (using their copy constructors) to their new locations. Then the `push_back`'d object is copied (by value) to the end.
2. The vector's memory block is large enough, new elements are copied (by value) to the end.

**How does the vector access the element?**

The same way you access a C-style array. `BasePointer + index`

Answer (score 2):

`vector::push_back` accepts a reference and then **reads the value at the reference to copy it into the vector.**

So the resulting vector would be

```
| A3 |
```

Note that when the vector is resized to accommodate the new data, it may move the old data to a new location, invalidating old references into it. So if the list A1, A2, … A5 *is* `v`,

```
v.push_back(A3)
```

will invalidate `A3` as `A3` references data inside `v`. The only way to keep a handle to data inside a vector as it grows is to save the index; references, pointers, and iterators will not do.

Comment: No, it won't invalidate A3, because it's done by value. The resulting vector will be | A3 | A3 |  in your example. Both objects are still valid.

Comment: @Billy: I stated the assumption that A3 is a reference to an object inside `v`. Read closer.

Comment: No, the OP says `push_back` takes a reference parameter, but that's it.

Comment: @Billy: That's why I used the word `if`: "So if the list A1, A2, … A5 is v,"

Answer (score 0):

```
|   A1     |     A2   |   A3     |    A4    |    A5    |   A3     |
```

The elements (like everything in the STL) are stored by value.

Vectors access elements just like built-in arrays.