# saving and loading vector<Mat> Qt & OpenCV

Tags: qt, opencv, mat, qimage, qdatastream

I'm working on face recognition in Qt & openCV using the FisherFaces recognizer which doesn't support updating so i have to save the faces database to retrain the recognizer after any changes.
 
Here is my code for saving :

```
save(const std::vector* MatVect){
       QFile file("students_dataset.dat");
       file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
       QDataStream out(&file);
       QVector qimgvect;
       for (size_t i = 0; i < MatVect->size(); ++i) 
       {
                cv::Mat matt = MatVect->at(i);
                QImage img((uchar*)matt.data, matt.cols, matt.rows, matt.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
                qimgvect.push_back(img);
        }
       out << qimgvect ;
       file.flush();
       file.close();
    }
```

and this is for loading :

```
load(std::vector* MatVect)
    {
    QFile file("students_dataset.dat");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in(&file);
    QVector qimgvect;
    in >> qimgvect;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < qimgvect.size(); ++i) 
      {
        QImage img = qimgvect.at(i);
        cv::Mat matt = cv::Mat(70, 70, CV_8U, img.bits(), img.bytesPerLine());
        MatVect->push_back(matt);
      }
    file.close();
    return;
    }
```

the problem is that what I read back from the file is not what i saved
[image: saved]
[image: loaded]

so what's exactly wrong in this code (hope not all of it ) ?
is there a better/easier way of saving the vector ?

**EDIT :**
thanks to ***Marek_R*** the conversion part is fixed, but saving and loading with QDataStream is the problem now :
[image: saved]
[image: loaded]
so what's causing those lines ?
**EDIT :**
I have tried this :
 
made `QimgVect` public and elemenated QDataStream part : **MatVect-> QimgVect** than **QimgVect->MatVect** and it did work fine, but after adding QDataStream : **MatVect-> QimgVect->QDataStream** and **QDataStream->QimgVect->MatVect** i get get the result shown above( vertical white lines ).
**EDIT**
converting the image from **RGB32** to **Indexed8** after reading from qdatastream gives the following result : 
[image]

Comment: image on the left is larger than image on the right, i guess, 70x70 is wrong

Comment: i tried `img.width(), img.height()` before but i got the same result ,so i used 70x70 because all the images are 70x70 as a result of some processioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO Here is a solution :
for saving grayscale `Qimage` through `QDataStream`  convert it to `Format_ARGB32` then save it, for loading convert it back to `Format_Indexed8` :
saving code

```
QFile file("students_dataset.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QDataStream out(&file);
//converting to ARGB32
foreach (QImage img, qimgvect) {
    img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
 }
// saving to QDataStream
out << qimgvect ;
file.flush();
file.close();
```

for loading

```
QFile file("students_dataset.dat");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in(&file);
QVector<QImage> qimgvect;
// loading images vector from QDatastream
in >> qimgvect;
// converting to grayscale
QVector<QRgb> grayscale;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) grayscale.append(qRgb(i, i, i));
for (int i, i < qimgvect.size(),i++) {  
    QImage img = qimgvect.at(i).convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Indexed8,grayscale);        
    qimgvect.push_back(img);
}

file.close();
```

I think even `QImage` with **other Formats** will face the same problem since it is assumed that the default format is `Format_ARGB32`

Answer (score 1):

this is memory management issue. When you create matrix from piece of memory copy of this memory is not created. At the same time this memory is disposed when `QImage` goes out of the scope.

Check answer about [converting between `QImage` and `cv:Mat`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17137998/1387438) (there is a better link in comment but for some reason page is not working so I didn't provided this link here).

When you are coping `cv::Mat` only a shallow copy is created. Actual Matrix contents is not copied. See [`cv::Mat` constructor documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat):

> **m** – Array that (as a whole or partly) is assigned to the constructed matrix. **No data is copied by these constructors**.
>   Instead, the header pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed
>   and associated with it. The reference counter, if any, is incremented.
>   So, when you modify the matrix formed using such a constructor, you
>   also modify the corresponding elements of m . **If you want to have an
>   independent copy of the sub-array, use `Mat::clone()`**

Comment: `qimgvect.push_back(img)` is taking a copy of the `img` before it goes out of scope

Comment: thank you that was the problem, here is what made me think it's copied [Q_about vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422273/one-question-about-vector-push-back), but now i have a new problem in `QDataStream` because i tested the code without it and it was working fine ,please see the edit