# How to write and read a QList<Mat> with QDataStream to and from a file?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have a QList contains a list of OpenCv::Mat. I'd like to write the QList to a file and read a file into a QList with QDataStream.

Here is part of  my code:

```
// Variables declarations
QList<Mat> myList;
cv::Mat someData;
QString fileName = "list.dat";
QFile file(fileName);
QDataStream out(&file);
QDataStream in(&file);

// Storing some data into the list
myList.append(someData);
myList.append(someData);
myList.append(someData);

// Writing the list to a file
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << myList;
file.close();

// Reading a file to the list
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
in >> myList;
file.close();
```

And I received two errors:

> error: C2678: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'QDataStream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>
> error: C2678: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'QDataStream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [saving and loading vector<Mat> Qt & OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073613/saving-and-loading-vectormat-qt-opencv)

Comment: `QDataStream & operator>>()` has no overload for `QList<Mat>`. you have to push_back (or so) in a loop...

Comment: You must provide the two operators your self, they should have a signature like these: `QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream&, const QList<Mat>&);` and  `QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const QList<Mat>&);`

Comment: You only need operators for the Mat type, Qt knows how to serialize QList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide those two operators for your custom type Mat :

```
QDataStream & operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Mat& mat)
QDataStream & operator>>(QDataStream &in, Mat& mat)
```

Comment: And write `return out << mat;` `return in >> mat;` inside of two functions?

Comment: Actually, you should de/serialize your object the way you want into the `QDataStream` and then call `return in` and `return out.` You have some examples here in the Qt doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#details . And here is en example of class serialization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt using QDataStream